# Eclipse common launch for several machine

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a project written in Java using Eclipse and I have a lot of users (students) that every day have to install and run it.

I'm searching a common configuration like `npm start`.

My idea is to install something or to say to my user: go in this directory and do this command for running like for Angular (`npm install & npm start`).

Is it possible or no?

Or to have a script that configure Eclipse workspace in automatically way.

Comment: What sort of Java program? A plain Java program - so it doesn't actually need Eclipse to run? An Eclipse plug-in? Something else? Why is an Eclipse workspace needed?

Comment: There is tomcat servers. In this project there are two tomcats servers